# Extract file name from file and insert it as column

Tags: file, ssh, append

I have a weird requirement, where I have some files placed in folder,

T_H_EDCGA.csv
c1 c2 c3
1  2  3
4  5  6

T_H_EDCOA.csv 
c1 c2 c3
7  8  9
10 11 13

I will append the contents of the above files, but i also want the last part of the file name ie EDCGA and EDCOA as column names

Result :
T_H_EDCGA.csv
c1  c2  c3  c4
1   2   3   EDCGA
4   5   6   EDCGA

T_H_EDCOA.csv
c1 c2  c3   c4 
7   8   9   EDCOA
10  11  13  EDCOA

Final result
1 2 3 EDCGA
4 5 6 EDCGA
7 8 9 EDCOA
10 11 13 EDCOA

Thanks